# Save function print result to html in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

In my code I have opened/using text file "id.txt" in a format as you can see below:

```
1: link1
2: link2
3: link3
4: link4
```

I have used def saveHTML() to update the text file to html code. Is it possible to save the result of a function saveHTML() to file_html "sample.html"?

```
Channel_name_before = '<p style="margin-top: 0px;"><span style="font-size: 6pt;"><strong><span style="background-color: #ccffcc;">'
Channel_name_after = '</span></strong></span></p>\n'
Beforeid = '[code]<div><a href="aceid" rel="nofollow"><button class="main-button-stream"><img class="main-button-img"'
Afterid = 'src="/language/ac/flag.svg" /> Click </button></a></div>[/code]\n'
1channel = [('1:','Test 1'),
            ('2:','Test 2'),]
file_txt = open('id.txt', "r")
content = file_txt.readlines()
def saveHTML():
    for line in content:
        id_name, id_ace = line.strip().split(': ')
        for 1_T in 1channel:
            1_number, 1_name = 1_T
            check1 =  any(item in 1_number for item in id_name)
            if check1 is True:
                print(Channel_name_before, 1_number, 1_name, Channel_name_after,
                      Beforeid.replace('aceid', id_acestream),Language, Afterid)

file_html = open('sample.html', "w")
file_html.write('<html>\n<head>Test1</head><body>\n<div align="center"><strong>Channels:</strong></div></br>\n<div class="columns">')
html_save_file = saveHTML()
print(html_save_file)
file_html.write(html_save_file)
file_html.write('</div>\n</body>\n</html>')
file_html.close()
file_txt.close()
```

Unfortunately file_html.write(html_save_file) is not working, the error is "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None", if I will add str(html_save_file), it will save as None to samle.html.

Hope someone could help me with that :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `saveHTML` implicitly returns `None`. You want to return a string value from the function.

Comment: OluwafemiSule's answer address the problem with your code. But it's really very basic approach to creating HTML file. Note that there are more sophisticated approaches to create the desired html file, like using template engines (e.g. Jinja2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that need correction:

- variables may not start with numbers
- `Language` has not been defined
- `saveHTML` does not actually save anything, it only prints variables to the console. Instead you could return them as joined string or something similar. I renamed it to `returnHTML`.

The following code procudes an HTML file, but further changes are needed. I guess this is not part of the question.

```
Channel_name_before = '<p style="margin-top: 0px;"><span style="font-size: 6pt;"><strong><span style="background-color: #ccffcc;">'
Channel_name_after = '</span></strong></span></p>\n'
Beforeid = '[code]<div><a href="aceid" rel="nofollow"><button class="main-button-stream"><img class="main-button-img"'
Afterid = 'src="/language/ac/flag.svg" /> Click </button></a></div>[/code]\n'
first_channel = [('1:','Test 1'),
            ('2:','Test 2'),]
file_txt = open('id.txt', "r")
content = file_txt.readlines()
Language = "English"
def returnHTML():
    html = ""
    for line in content:
        id_name, id_ace = line.strip().split(': ',1)
        for first_T in first_channel:
            first_number, first_name = first_T
            check1 =  any(item in first_number for item in id_name)
            if check1 is True:
                html +=" ".join([Channel_name_before, first_number, first_name, Language, Channel_name_after,
                      Beforeid.replace('aceid', id_ace), Afterid])
    return html

file_html = open('sample.html', "w")
file_html.write('<html>\n<head>Test1</head><body>\n<div align="center"><strong>Channels:</strong></div></br>\n<div class="columns">')
html_save_file = returnHTML()
print(html_save_file)
file_html.write(html_save_file)
file_html.write('</div>\n</body>\n</html>')
file_html.close()
file_txt.close()
```